# Verify Checkbox.Checked from static method

Tags: c#, exception, static

I'm developing a web page for clients to request exemptions from certain requirements.  There is a list of 14 CheckBoxes, each with two subsequent Checkboxes.  The code to check which of them are checked will be placed in the submit button.  This method is in the code behind.  Here's the code for that (so far)

```
[WebMethod]
public void SendForm(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        throw new Exception("You must supply an email address.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (IsValidEmailAddress(email))
        {
            bool[] desc = new bool[14];
            bool[] local = new bool[14];
            bool[] other = new bool[14];

            for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
            {
                desc[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkDesc" + i.ToString())).Checked;
                local[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkLocal" + i.ToString())).Checked;
                other[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkOther" + i.ToString())).Checked;

                /* Do stuff here */
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("You must supply a valid email address.");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error "An object reference iw required for the non-static field, method, or property..."

In the aspx page I have the button and the javascript/ajax that calls the button in the codebehind.  Shown here:

```
<table width='750' align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>
            <label>Please Provide your email address:</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>
            <fieldset id="Fieldset">
                <button onclick="SendForm();">
                    Send</button>               
                &nbsp;
                <button onclick="CancelForm();">
                    Cancel</button>                  
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendForm() {
        var email = $get("txtEmail").value;

        PageMethods.SendForm(email, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    }

    function OnSucceeded() {
        $get("Fieldset").innerHTML = "<p>Thank you!</p>";
    }

    function OnFailed(error) {
        alert(error.get_message());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the whole page isn't posted back with a web method.

Comment: For starters make your int 1 start at 0 get rid of the <= are you a VB programmer converting over to C# if so keep in mind C# for loops and array accessing and things like that are zero based.

Comment: indeed this would be better put in the code behind and pass the arrays as a parameter

Comment: Why is the submit button using an AJAX method? Unless you didn't actually mean "submit"?

Comment: Edited post to more accurately depict the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, you can't refer to the controls of a page in the static method until and unless you explicitly pass a reference of the "Page" object to the web method you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have the following code:

```
bool[] desc = new bool[14];
bool[] local = new bool[14];
bool[] other = new bool[14];

for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
{
    desc[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkDesc" + i.ToString())).Checked;
    local[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkLocal" + i.ToString())).Checked;
    other[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkOther" + i.ToString())).Checked;

    /* Do stuff here */
}
```

Why don't you have this validation code in a Class in your project.. is there a reason why you are trying to access the PageControls using this code

```
if (IsValidEmailAddress(email))         
{             
   for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
   { 
     CheckBox chkBox = chkDesc1.Checked;
   }
}
```

Change your for loop and start i = 0 and change <= 14 to < 13 C# is 0 based
Place the whole method signature .. you are probably trying to call a non static method inside of your application either add the word static to the method or remove but I would rather see how you have the method created.. also where are you creating the instance of the WebMethod Class object..?